# Android force closing when trying to use release(); to stop MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, xml

I am creating an app that will play load a MediaPlayer at the beginning then after a few seconds this class will be destroyed and move to another class. The problem is I'm trying to stop the MediaPlayer whenever the first class gets destroyed but it will just force close on me. here's the code.

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp;    

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.otj);
        mp.start();

        Thread LogoTimer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int LogoTimer = 0;
                    while(LogoTimer < 5000) {
                        sleep(100);
                        LogoTimer = LogoTimer + 100;
                    }

                    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.HelloWorld.CLEARSCREEN"));
                } 

                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        LogoTimer.start();
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In `onCreate()` you declare another variable called `mp`, which shadows the class field `mp`, which means the `mp` you call on `onDestroy()` is **null**.

Remove `final MediaPlayer` from the line `final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.otj);` so you'd use the original all of the time.

Your code should look like:

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.otj);
    mp.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

what about the mp.release(); it's the one that should stop the mediaplayer but whenever the onDestroy(){} runs it will force close.